# Convert zip file to bytes in python

Tags: python, zip

Goal for question - open a zip file and convert it into a bytes-like object.

When I tried I get the error:

```
encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

Here is the code:

```
import base64

with open("results.zip", 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    print(data)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
```

I also tried this and got the same exact error:

```
import zipfile

with open("results.zip", 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(data), "r")
    for fileinfo in zf.infolist():
        print(zf.read(fileinfo).decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: It's unclear what your ultimate objective is. If you open a file (**any** file) in 'rb' mode and call the file handle's *read()* function, you will get a reference to a *bytes* class which, from the way your question is phrased, seems to be what you need

Comment: @vlad OMG - Thank you, your simple statement fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Vlad for his comment as it helped me to get the answer.

```
import base64

with open("results.zip", 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
```